# How to delete recodrs using sysdate through informatica

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter

I have developed a mapping in informatica.Source is file .I need to write a post sql that will delete the already existing data if the file with same name comes again.File comes once in every month and naming is like jass_naming_yyyymm.csv .I have written like delete from tab where load_date = sysdate but its not working.laod date is a column in target table taht stores yyyymm from the file.So query shoud be like if file with existing yyyymm comes again the existing data should get deleted and new file will be loaded.
Please give soluntion.

Comment: Src->exp->tgt.In source i have enabled currently processed file.In exp i have extracted the yyyymm from the file received in the column load_date and file name in another column as file_name.It is indirect load mapping.Now i want to inplement the logic to delete the existing data and replace with the new file if same file comes again with some modification in a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post SQL will not help here. You need two pipelines.
Pipeline 1 - Src->exp->tgt. 
Use indirect file read method, get file name to fetch yyyy_mm part from file name.
You need to use 'update override' option in the target to delete the data. Use this logic -
`DELETE FROM target_table WHERE target_yyyy_mm= :TU.source_yyyy_mm`
[image]
Pipeline 2 - your mapping.

HTH